# Permissions within Windows symlink to a Samba share

Tags: windows-7, samba, symbolic-link, symlink

I have a Samba shared folder on an Ubuntu box which I can access from my Windows 7 PC and within which, as a non-administrator Windows user, can create and update files and folders.

However, when I create a symlink in Windows to this folder using mklink /d I find that all the folders in that share have a padlock Symbol on them in Windows Explorer, and when I right-click within those folders and click "New", the only option is "Folder" with an administrator-shield symbol next to it, rather than the normal file types I can create.  I can go to the Security settings for any of folders within the symlink and give Modify permissions to "Everyone" which removes the padlock symbol and then allows me to right-click and create other file types, but I have to do this for every folder individually, and any new folders that are created get the padlock symbol and restricted file-type list.

I want the symlink to behave exactly the same as when I access the share directly.  Is this possible?

I don't get the same problem when creating a symlink to a shared folder from another Windows box or another folder on the same PC.